# is there some method of array like set in python?

Tags: javascript, list, arraylist

As I know in python i can set a list to a unique list like:

```
In [12]: a=range(12)

In [13]: a.append(5)

In [14]: a.append(4)

In [15]: a.append(5)

In [16]: a
Out[16]: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 5, 4, 5]

In [17]: set(a)
Out[17]: set([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11])
```

it is very useful  for some scene,
i just want to know how to this in javascript,

Comment: I recommend very highly that you search Google before you ask questions here.
I Googled it and found that there is no native 'Set' in Javascript. It will be simple to implement your own Set data-structure.

Comment: The question was at the top of google when I searched.

Answer (score 11):

Javascript does not have the notion of sets. However, you can use a side effect of the fact that objects cannot have duplicate property names to replicate the functionality of a set, as seen on [this blog article about the topic](http://community.service-now.com/blog/slightlyloony/4113).

From the article:

```
var your_array = ['a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b'],
    set = {};
for (var i = 0; i < your_array.length; i++)
   set[your_array[i]] = true;
list = [];
for (var item in set)
   list.push(item);
```

**EDIT in 2017:** This is no longer true, JS got set support! [MDN Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set)

```
empty_set = new Set()
three_element_set = new Set([1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3])
three_element_set.add(3) // still three element set
```

Answer (score 1):

No, there isn't. JS is pretty basic, you have to either do it yourself or find a library where someone else has already done it.

The standard way to do this is usually insert elements into a hash, then collect the keys - since keys are guaranteed to be unique. Or, similarly, but preserving order:

```
function uniq(arr) {
  var seen = {}, result = [];
  var len = arr.len;
  for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    var el = arr[i];
    if (!seen[el]) {
      seen[el] = true;
      result.push(el);
    }
  }
  return result;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a Set object with the Set() constructor. The argument to the Set() constructor need not be an array: any iterable object (including other Set objects) is allowed.

```
 let myArray = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 5, 4, 5]
 let mySet = new Set(myArray); //output: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11]
```

Another example:

```
  let unique = new Set("Mississippi"); //output: [ "M", "i", "s", "p" ]
```

ref. JavaScript_ The Definitive Guide, David Flanagan -(2020)

Answer (score 0):

Firefox 13+ provides an experimental implementation of sets. [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript%2FReference%2FGlobal_Objects%2FSet).

Answer (score 0):

Very late to the party, but as of ECMAScript 2015 the "[experimental implementation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set)" mentioned in [mquandalle's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17266803/6605349) is no longer experimental and is instead part of the standard. [Browser compatibility](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set#Browser_compatibility)